# I have a function which takes an implicit parameter. How can I pass the parameter implicitly using implicit parameters of an instance of some class?

Tags: scala, inheritance, parameter-passing, implicit

This is the function:

```
def execute[T, U, F[_]](t: T)(implicit
                                executor: Executor[F],
                                functor: Functor[F],
                                handler: Handler[T, U],
                                manifest: Manifest[U]): F[Response[U]] = {(do something)}
```

I have a class `ElasticSearchRepositoryWrapper` which inherits from somewhere (I couldn't find from where) `handler` variable. 
I have an instance of the class `repo = ElasticSearchRepositoryWrapper(client, config, configName)`
I want to do that:

```
class SomeService(val config: Config,
                             val configName: String = "products",
                             val client: ElasticClient)
                            (implicit val ec: ExecutionContext)
{
    repo = ElasticSearchRepositoryWrapper(client, config, configName)
    repo.client.execute {
      repo.delete(something)
    }
}
```

but it says, `No implicits found for parameter handler: Handler[..., ...]` for `execute` function
So, how can I pass that `handler` from `repo` to it?
Note: if class `SomeService` inherits from `ElasticSearchRepositoryWrapper` it finds it.

Comment: Can you access to the handler from repo var?

Comment: @EmiCareOfCell44  No, I can't access

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what is the first parameter of `execute`. It looks like it wants some `t`, but you are passing in a block (not saying it is necessarily wrong, but kinda weird). But, assuming, that is indeed what you want, and `repo.handler` is accessible, you can pass it like this:

```
  repo.client.execute(repo.delete(something))(ec, implicitly, repo.handler, implicitly)
```

Comment: Oh, that is the problem - I can't access repo.handler

Comment: In that case you are out of luck. You can't use things that you can't access :)